# diff between Ros driver and normal linux driver

Tags: ros, linux, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
i am very new in ROS

i have a coupled of questions,

What is the difference between linux driver and ROS driver?

Application code should be in c++ or in C works?

How 2d and 3d sensor works?

i have to capture specific object, how can i do it without using kinet?

Thanks in Advance

please answer as i am stuck badly, i will keep you in prayer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199736/diff-between-ros-driver-and-normal-linux-driver/) by [shah shufi](https://answers.ros.org/users/21161/shah-shufi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shah shufi](https://answers.ros.org/users/21161/shah-shufi/) on 2014-12-18**:
please help

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-12-19**:
Your project sounds really complex to me.
I think yu should have already clear which hardware, devices, and already existing frames exist to develop such a robot.
Since your target seems very high, I cannot judge whether ROS is ok for you or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually you don't have to take care about that.
ROS is a framework in which you write C++ (C++03) applications which dialog with the underlyind drivers.
Take as an example a joystick. You plug the joystick in the PC and it will be recognized by the linux kernel.
If you want to use the joystick In ROS then you write an application which *commnicates* with those drivers. So you don't touch the hardware directly. Simply look for a linux driver for that device and don't care about it anymore.
The main idea behind this concept is that ROS takes care about communication betweens many nodes, that's all.
In this way you install a sensor/hardwware/device in linux as you never heard about ROS. The related device's drivers usually let you to speak directly to the hardware or provides some useful functions, that can be called from your code.
The next step is then writing a code in ROS which dialogs with those drivers but doesn't touch your device/sensors...
and for this you must use C++

In a rare case, where you need to write C or to create an interface for a device, which has/has no C++ support, you can use the following C++ directive in your surce file:

```
extern "C" {
// code
}
```

and write C code.

Or we can have the following situation. You have bought a new device, let's say a 9 DOF accelerometers, gyroscope and magnetometer (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736). And for this device you don't have any driver yet. The only thing you want is to get data from the device for your application.
What you can do is getting the serial raw data output from the device into ROS though serial interface (with [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial)) and there write your application for working with that datas. In this case you didn't need specifically a driver for that device. In the same manner you could plug your camera, a sensor, a I2C interface, and so on.

For many motor drivers, interfaces and so on there are ready to use ROS-packages available.
On the next level you need (maybe) a package to work with that datas and...for example, implement a Kalman filter for your application. Even in that case you have many available ROS-packages raedy to use. So you don't need to write and debug your Kalman filter, spending 2 months of your life debbing that code. Some other people wrote already a *stable* application (package) and share it with others.
Another example could be kinematic transformation for a robot arm. If you look in a book about robotics you understand very fast, that writing a code for that is too expansive.

Why ROS: the main idea behind ROS concept's is: we have many applications (*nodes*) which differents tasks. What I need is a way to let them to comunicate (*publishing and listening*) each other those streams (*topics*) of informations.
Thats all.

Regards

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shah shufi](https://answers.ros.org/users/21161/shah-shufi/) on 2014-12-19**:
THANKS A LOT

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-12-23**:
@shah shufi Please try to ask smaller more concrete questions in the future that can have concrete answers and don't couple several questions together so different people can answer the different questions.